# remove border from dijit layout tabcontainer and content panes

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I have a dijit/layout/tablcontainer with content panes as the tabs.  Is there anyway I can remove the outside border?  I don't see any border properties in either widget.  I've tried css for the div the widgets are within and not having any luck.  I'm using a black background and the border appears white.

Here are some more details in response to Rohan's comment:

I have three divs: one that contains the dijit/layout/tabcontainer and two that contain the dijit/layout/contentpanes wrapped inside the tabcontainer div.  The css I'm trying is below

```
  #tc {
width: 350px;
height: 300px;
background-color: black;
margin: 0 auto;
border-width: 0px;
/*margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;*/
}
#FSHours {
width: 350px;
height: 250px;
background-color: black;
margin: 0 auto;
border-width: 0px;
}
#FSTickets {
width: 350px;
height: 250px;
background-color: black;
margin: 0 auto;
border-width: 0px;
}
```

Maybe its not possible, but I'm hoping to remove/hide the border around the control with the title 'Field Staff Tickets'[image] that you can see in the screen shot

Thanks

Pete

Comment: Can you share what you tried & what output are you expecting?

Comment: I edited my original post with more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to remove the style from tab titles in tab container, the dijit classes for tab title are `dijitTab` & `dijitTabChecked`.

You can try setting

```
/* if #tc is your tabContainer id */
#tc .dijitTab {
    background-image: none;
    border: 0;
}

#tc .dijitTab.dijitTabChecked {
    /* some style to indicade active tab */
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Hope this helps, or you will need to update your question accordingly.